# Why doesnt the JVM terminate in this case?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, jvm, resource-leak

I think I have a thread leak in my code, but I am not sure why. Here is the code -

```
foo(String solutionFileName, String SubmissionFileName){
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
    Future<BufferedReader> f1 = e.submit(new Builder(solutionFileName));
    Future<BufferedReader> f2 = e.submit(new Builder(submissionFileName));
    BufferedReader b1=f1.get();
    BufferedReader b2=f2.get();
    //do a little work
    e.shutdown();
}

class Builder{
    Builder(String fileName){this.fileName=fileName;}
    public BufferedReader call() throws FileNotFoundException{
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
    String fileName;
    }
}
```

Im running this off Eclipse and the problem is that when I hit a FileNotFoundException the JVM doesnt die. I have to manually terminate it. I dont understand why though...

Comment: Please show us executable code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I showed you all the code that is relevant.

Comment: Please show us compilable and executable code. If this is meant to be pseudo code, please make sure you state it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I thought that was kind of self evident, given by the fact that there is no return type, the gets dont have a try/catch around them, and I have that do a little work comment.... And even just that was enough to solve my problem. No full file needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> problem is that when I hit a FileNotFoundException

When you hit this exception it seems your exception handler not shutting down `ExecutorService`. If you don't shutdown `ExecutorService`, that thread pool will stay there.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to do that. I just put one shut down at the end and assumed it was enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `try`/`finally` block:

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
try {
    Future<BufferedReader> f1 = e.submit(new Builder(solutionFileName));
    Future<BufferedReader> f2 = e.submit(new Builder(submissionFileName));
    BufferedReader b1=f1.get();
    BufferedReader b2=f2.get();
    //do a little work
} finally {
    e.shutdown();
}
```

This will cause the `shutdown` call to be executed no matter how the `try` block is exited. Your code is throwing the exception, which causes the `e.shutdown()` line to be skipped (exceptions normally cause all code execution to stop). By adding the `finally`, you're guaranteeing that no matter how the `try` block exits, the `e.shutdown()` is called.

There's one exception. If you do this:

```
try {
    System.exit(0);
} finally {
    System.out.println("Finally block");
}
```

`"Finally Block"` will never be printed because `System.exit` never returns normally.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown in a separate thread. The thread spawn in the `es.call()` should die but not the main thread (or the thread running the `foo()`). 
And the JVM is still running because the main thread is not died.